# How to find what's stored next to a certain variable

Tags: c++, xcode, variables

I'm currently battling with an intermittent bug. I create a float member of my class. I initialize it to zero. And then give it a value. This variable is used several times over the course of the next few processes, and inexplicably it will sometimes change its value to a really small number and cause an error in my program. I've pinpointed the general area in my code where it happens, and I swear, there is nothing in my code that is acting upon this variable. And on top of that I'll run and compile the same exact program with the same exact code several times and this bug only pops up sometimes.

I'm thinking that one of my other arrays or pointers is occasionally stepping out of bounds (because I haven't implemented bounds checking yet) and replacing the variables value with it's own, but I have no idea which one. I was wondering if there is a way in XCode, to find out what variables are stored near or next to this variable, so I can maybe pinpoint who might be stepping on this poor little son of a gun?

Comment: some profiling tool like valgrind or rational purify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable "guard malloc" in XCode. Guard malloc can tell you whether your code wrote out of bounds on any allocated area. I don't know the exact way to enable it (anymore), but you'll definitely find something on the nets.

Comment: You can launch Instruments from XCode which helps in hunting down such problems.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to watch some memory location while debugging your code with `gdb` you can use `watch` breakpoints.

Maybe you have a corrupted memory heap. Using a tool like `valgrind` could help.